# static string weird behavior Diamond Star Pattern problem

Tags: java, algorithm

I'm trying to solve this problem given a number 5, we display:

```
    *
  *****
*********
  *****
    *
```

And so on. So you give it a number and it format it for you like above. I tried to solve it using this code bellow and I can't see where the problem is in my code.

```
public class Exe01 {
    public static String space = "";//global space var 
    public static String ast = "";//global * var 


    public static String adjustAst(int numOfAst) {
        Exe01.ast = "";
        for (int i = numOfAst; i > 0; i--) {
            Exe01.ast+="*";
        }
        return Exe01.ast;
    }

    public static String adjustSpaces(int numOfSpaces) {
        Exe01.space = "";
        for (int i = numOfSpaces; i > 0; i--) {
            Exe01.space = Exe01.space + " ";
        }
        return Exe01.space;
    }

    public static void showAst(int num) {
        if (num <= 0 || num % 2 == 0)
            System.out.println("arg to the function need to be positive and odd");
        else if (num == 1)
            System.out.println("*");
        else {
            int mid = (int) (num / 2);
            int numberOfSpaces = num - 1;
            for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
                int k = 0;
                if (i < mid) {
                    k = k * 2 + 1;
                    System.out.println(Exe01.adjustSpaces(numberOfSpaces) + Exe01.adjustAst(k));
                    numberOfSpaces = numberOfSpaces - 2;
                } else if (i == mid) {
                    numberOfSpaces = 0;
                    k = k * 2 + 1;
                    System.out.println(Exe01.adjustSpaces(numberOfSpaces) + Exe01.adjustAst(k));
                    numberOfSpaces = numberOfSpaces + 2;
                } else {
                    k = k - 4;
                    System.out.println(Exe01.adjustSpaces(numberOfSpaces) + Exe01.adjustAst(k));
                    numberOfSpaces = numberOfSpaces + 2;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Exe01.showAst(5);
    }

}
```

At compilation time it gives me this:

```
    *
  *
*
```

Comment: "at compilation time it give me this" you get that at *runtime*.

Comment: I've not looked at your code in detail, but the use of global variables is deeply suspicious. You don't need anything like this.

Comment: ya as a result in the output

Comment: at least is my code and i'm happy with it as my first real problem i take xD

Comment: Sounds like a perfect time to learn how to use the debugger. Once you do that you should be able to narrow down the issue to something more specific than "my code doesn't work".

Comment: what is this "debugger" ?

Comment: i used google to get here, i just want to learn what the problem in my code that's it

Comment: What tool do you use to run this piece of code? If it's a decent IDE, you should be able to use the debugging feature of it

Comment: vs code but i don't know what this debbuging  is so i'm not getting what u mean

Comment: 1st google hit when I search "VS Code debug java" -> https://code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2017/09/28/java-debug

Comment: It looks like your reasoning is generally right. But there are many problems with this code. The part that's keeping you from seeing the diamond is the location of the line `int k = 0;` Debuggers are nice. But with code this simple it's probably more worthwhile to step through it yourself with `num` set at a small value (say 3). Use a bit of paper or an editor to track the values of variables. If you're careful, you'll reproduce what your code is doing. While you're doing that, the problem should become clear. This will be much more satisfying than asking us for the answer.